# Manipulating contents of array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, iterator, iteration

I have a piece of code where I am trying to manipulate the contents of an array

```
loopArrayValuesToRemove(mVal.getValues());
```

Here I am trying to remove the contents of the array of values

```
private Values[] loopArrayValuesToRemove(Values[] values) {

    List<Values> files = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(values.clone()));
    Iterator<Values> iterator = files.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        Values mVal = iterator.next();
        if(!mVal.isCheckedLocally()){
            iterator.remove();
        }
        // other operations
    }
    Values[] mvals = files.toArray(new Values[files.size()]);

    return mvals;
}
```

1. Since I am creating the new object even if I manipulate `Values[]`,
   `mVal.getValues()` contents are not modified.
2. It's a Silly question, but I am stuck at this. as I cannot change the
   response to arrayList in server at (`mVal.getValues()`)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Question is regarding modifying reference of `mVal.getValues()` contents

Comment: You're going to have to explain yourself better than that. What do you want to happen and what is happening?

Comment: I ll try : ....`mVal.getValues()` is having a array of values .... based on a condition I am modifying its contents , In the question I have modified the contents by converting to list since array has fixed size but the issue is, Though list is modified original `mVal.getValues()` remains unchanged

Comment: Had you tried to full new list with valid elements instead od removing invalid?  Should be faster and less time cinsuming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to write it as

```
mVal.setValues(loopArrayValuesToRemove(mVal.getValues()));
```

Due to Java passing references by value, you can't change the array itself inside the method. Contents can be changed, but if the size changes it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, your goal is to remove instances from the List which `isCheckedLocally()` returns true,

You can use the Stream API since Java 8.

```
mVal = mVal.stream()
    .filter(i -> i.isCheckedLocally())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: there is *// other operations* you can never be sure if the filter by you can solve all of it